# Relationship of a section cut parallel to a base of a pyramid and its height proof

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Is there an algebraic proof for this? I was trying to solve how this relationship was made. Thanks! Also, what is the proper name for this relationship?

[image: Source and Picture: Solid Mensuration, Second Edition by Willis F. Kern, James R. Bland, Page 46]

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)) article about similarity. The article only talks about 2D shapes, but the same concept applies here. An algebraic proof is not needed here. The pyramid which only consists of the top $x$ units is similar to the whole pyramid. The ratio of the lengths of each pyramid is $\dfrac{x}{h}$. Hence, the ratio of the area of the bottom section of each pyramid is $\dfrac{x^2}{h^2}$.

The name of this relationship is simply "similarity".

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Comment: Thanks! But its says I need 15 reputation to cast an upvote because I am only new to the website. But I appreciate your answer very much!

Comment: Are you sure? If I remember it newcomers are allowed to upvote on their own question. I'll search up on this.